# Board game: steady state probability of being in starting location (GO)

Tags: probability, markov-chains, steady-state

Considering a board game which has 20 positions only. There are 2 fair dice that can be rolled and the player moves in a clockwise position over the board positions. Considering that the dice are fair and player moves around the board as per the dice roll, how can I compute the steady state probability of being in the starting location (GO i.e. the bottom right position)?

I am thinking that since the average dice roll sum is 7, so the steady state probability of being in any position on the board is $\frac{1}{7}$. Therefore it would be the same for the starting location as well. However, I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of being on any square at all is the sum of the probabilities of being on the particular squares. Thus, if your result $\frac17$ were correct, the probability of being on any square at all would have to be $\frac{20}7$. It is in fact $1$, so the probability of being on any particular square is ...?

Note that this probability has nothing to do with how many dice you roll or their average; it depends only on the number of squares.

Comment: "so the probability of being on any particular square is" 1/20. If the probability has nothing to do with roll dice, it means the steady state probability of a board game with 40 positions would be 1/40, and likewise?

Comment: @JohnBolton: Indeed.